# Android: SimpleDateFormat changes year of my date

Tags: android, date-format

I am using SimpleDateFormat to change format of date, shown below. But it somehow changes my year from for example 2016 to 2019 or 2018. How could I make it work correctly?

```
    String date = "2016-10-22 13:45:46.000000";

    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-mm-dd HH:MM:SS");
    Date testDate = null;
    try {
        testDate = sdf.parse(date);
    }catch(Exception ex){
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
    SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd.mm.yyyy HH:MM");
    String newFormat = formatter.format(testDate);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must be careful to use the right casing (either upper or lower) for all the date/time pattern strings, as specified in the [SimpleDateFormat Javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

Uppercase `M` is used for "Month in year", and lowercase `m` is used for "Minute in hour".

Uppercase `S` is used for "Millisecond", and lowercase `s` is used for "second in minute".

This should work properly:

```
String date = "2016-10-22 13:45:46.000000";

SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
Date testDate = null;
try {
    testDate = sdf.parse(date);
}catch(Exception ex){
    ex.printStackTrace();
}

SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm");
String newFormat = formatter.format(testDate);
```

Comment: Works perfectly. Thanks.